# How to run mongodb docker instance with custom configuration file?

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodb-query

I have executed the command 
`sudo docker run -p 37017:27017 -v /data:/data/db -v /logs:/var/log/mongodb/ -v /etc/:/etc/ --name mongocustom -d bbed8d0e01c1 --config /etc/newmongod.conf`.
but soon the container exited with an error.
docker logs gives following output:

`sudo docker logs mongocustom`

`parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 14
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 14
Error parsing YAML config file: yaml-cpp: error at line 16, column 12: illegal map value
try 'mongod --help' for more information`

So where I went wrong.

Comment: Why are you mounting the volume  `-v /etc/:/etc/`? Seems like MongoDB is not getting the correct configurations. Can you show the contents of `newmongod.conf`?

Comment: # where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /data
  journal: /journal
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.


#security:

Comment: I ran into the same problem. ```docker run -ti -p 127.0.0.1:27017:27017 --name mongo -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin --network net-1 --network-alias mongo --restart always -v /mongodb/db:/data/db -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -v /srv/mongo:/etc/mongo --privileged=true -d mongo --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf```